# Istio Prometheus pod in CrashLoopBackOff State

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I am trying to setup Istio (1.5.4) for the bookinfo example provided on their [website](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/). I have used the demo configuration profile. But on verifying istio installation it fails since Prometheus pod has entered a CrashLoopBackOff state.

```
   NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-5f6f8cbf75-psk78               1/1     Running            0          21m
istio-egressgateway-7f9f45c966-g7k9j   1/1     Running            0          21m
istio-ingressgateway-968d69c8b-bhxk5   1/1     Running            0          21m
istio-tracing-9dd6c4f7c-7fm79          1/1     Running            0          21m
istiod-86884c8c45-sw96x                1/1     Running            0          21m
kiali-869c6894c5-wqgjb                 1/1     Running            0          21m
prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj            1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   8          21m
```

The logs for the prometheus pod:

```
level=warn ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.113Z caller=main.go:283 deprecation_notice="'storage.tsdb.retention' flag is deprecated use 'storage.tsdb.retention.time' instead."
level=info ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.114Z caller=main.go:330 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.15.1, branch=HEAD, revision=8744510c6391d3ef46d8294a7e1f46e57407ab13)"
level=info ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.114Z caller=main.go:331 build_context="(go=go1.13.5, user=root@4b1e33c71b9d, date=20191225-01:04:15)"
level=info ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.114Z caller=main.go:332 host_details="(Linux 4.15.0-52-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj (none))"
level=info ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.114Z caller=main.go:333 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
level=info ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.114Z caller=main.go:334 vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
level=error ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.157Z caller=query_logger.go:107 component=activeQueryTracker msg="Failed to create directory for logging active queries"
level=error ts=2020-05-15T09:07:53.157Z caller=query_logger.go:85 component=activeQueryTracker msg="Error opening query log file" file=data/queries.active err="open data/queries.active: no such file or directory"
panic: Unable to create mmap-ed active query log

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql.NewActiveQueryTracker(0x24dda5b, 0x5, 0x14, 0x2c62100, 0xc0005f63c0, 0x2c62100)
    /app/promql/query_logger.go:115 +0x48c
main.main()
    /app/cmd/prometheus/main.go:362 +0x5229
```

Describe pod output:

```
Name:         prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj
Namespace:    istio-system
Priority:     0
Node:         inspiron-7577/192.168.0.9
Start Time:   Fri, 15 May 2020 14:21:14 +0530
Labels:       app=prometheus
              pod-template-hash=589c44dbfc
              release=istio
Annotations:  sidecar.istio.io/inject: false
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.11
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.11
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/prometheus-589c44dbfc
Containers:
  prometheus:
    Container ID:  docker://b6820a000ab67a5ce31d3a38f6f0d510bd150794b2792147fc17ef8f730c03bb
    Image:         docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.15.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://prom/prometheus@sha256:169b743ceb4452266915272f9c3409d36972e41cb52f3f28644e6c0609fc54e6
    Port:          9090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --storage.tsdb.retention=6h
      --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Fri, 15 May 2020 14:37:50 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 15 May 2020 14:37:53 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
    Liveness:     http-get http://:9090/-/healthy delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:9090/-/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio-certs from istio-certs (rw)
      /etc/prometheus from config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-token-cgqbc (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://fa756c93510b6f402d7d88c31a5f5f066d4c254590eab70886e7835e7d3871be
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.4
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:e16e2801b7fd93154e8fcb5f4e2fb1240d73349d425b8be90691d48e8b9bb944
    Port:          15090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --configPath
      /etc/istio/proxy
      --binaryPath
      /usr/local/bin/envoy
      --serviceCluster
      istio-proxy-prometheus
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system.svc:15012
      --proxyLogLevel=warning
      --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
      --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
      NONE
      --dnsRefreshRate
      300s
      --statusPort
      15020
      --trust-domain=cluster.local
      --controlPlaneBootstrap=false
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 15 May 2020 14:21:31 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Readiness:      http-get http://:15020/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      OUTPUT_CERTS:                 /etc/istio-certs
      JWT_POLICY:                   first-party-jwt
      PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER:          istiod
      CA_ADDR:                      istio-pilot.istio-system.svc:15012
      POD_NAME:                     prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                istio-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                   (v1:status.podIP)
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT:               (v1:spec.serviceAccountName)
      HOST_IP:                       (v1:status.hostIP)
      ISTIO_META_POD_NAME:          prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj (v1:metadata.name)
      ISTIO_META_CONFIG_NAMESPACE:  istio-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      ISTIO_META_MESH_ID:           cluster.local
      ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID:        Kubernetes
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio-certs/ from istio-certs (rw)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/istio from istiod-ca-cert (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-token-cgqbc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      prometheus
    Optional:  false
  istio-certs:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istiod-ca-cert:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio-ca-root-cert
    Optional:  false
  prometheus-token-cgqbc:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  prometheus-token-cgqbc
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From                    Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled    <unknown>             default-scheduler       Successfully assigned istio-system/prometheus-589c44dbfc-xkwmj to inspiron-7577
  Warning  FailedMount  17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "prometheus-token-cgqbc" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   Pulled       17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  Created container istio-proxy
  Normal   Started      17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  Started container istio-proxy
  Warning  Unhealthy    17m                   kubelet, inspiron-7577  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Normal   Pulled       16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet, inspiron-7577  Container image "docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.15.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet, inspiron-7577  Created container prometheus
  Normal   Started      16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet, inspiron-7577  Started container prometheus
  Warning  BackOff      2m24s (x72 over 17m)  kubelet, inspiron-7577  Back-off restarting failed container
```

It is unable to create directory for logging. Please help with any ideas.

Comment: Could you tell me how did you install your istio? It was `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo` or you have add something? Could you please add output from `kubectl describe pod prometheus-589c44dbfc-z8z29  -n istio-system` to your question? Have you tried to delete istio namespace and install istio again?

Comment: @jt97: I have re-installed istio and the error still persists. Added the pod description. I did use `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo` for installation.

Comment: I made a test on gcp and it works without any problem, in fact i got the same error on minikube but the pod restarted and is running now, could you confirm after some time this pod is running or it's 1/2 CrashLoopBackOff for you all the time?

Comment: @jt97: I am running on minkube as well. It has been 1/2 CrashLoopBackOff even after several restarts. Could it be due to permission problems?

Comment: I have an idea, could you try to delete istio namespace, then install istio operator with `istioctl operator init` and then install istio as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/#install)? I think this is a problem with istioctl, not a permissions. Checked it on minikube now and this error not occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jt97! It did work. Could you tell me why the normal installation failed?

Comment: As istio 1.5.4 has been just released I assume there is some issue with prometheus. I will add an answer with istio operator as a workaround, if I found the issue I will update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [istio 1.5.4](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5.4/) has been just released there are some issues with prometheus on minikube installed with istioctl manifest apply.

I checked it on a gcp and everything works fine there.

---

As a workaround, you can use [istio operator](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/) which was tested by me and OP and as he mentioned in comments, it's working.

> Thanks a lot @jt97! It did work.

---

Steps to install istio operator

- [Install](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) the istioctl command.
- [Deploy](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/#prerequisites) the Istio operator: `istioctl operator init`.
- [Install](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/#install) istio

> To install the Istio demo configuration profile using the operator, run the following command:

```
kubectl create ns istio-system
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
EOF
```

---

> Could you tell me why the normal installation failed?

As I mentioned in comments, I don't know yet. If I found a reason I will update this question.